# link_to home page from subdomain page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to rails development and I'm working on a website. The site has a subdomain but also has a navigation bar that is on all pages including the subdomain page. One of the links on the navigation bar is a link to the sites homepage (not the subdomain home page). Currently this is set doing the following:

```
<h1><a href="http://(URL to Home page)">WEBSITE NAME</a></h1>
```

I realize this is not the rails way to do things. So I was trying to use `link_to` but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried the following:

```
<h1><%= link_to "WEBSITE NAME", :controller => "home", :action => "index"%></h1>
```

where `"home"` is the name of the controller for the main page.

This works fine on the main page, but whenever I'm on a a subdomain page it just loads the subdomains home page. After inspecting the element the generated html looks like:

```
<h1><a href="/">WEBSITE NAME</a><h1>
```

I guess it makes sense that it loads the subdomain's home page, but I want to load the site's home page, even on the subdomain pages. How would I do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main site is running as a separate application. In that case you cannot link to the home page by specifying the controller and action. You will have to specify the full url

```
<h1><%= link_to "WEBSITE NAME", "http://(URL to home page)"%></h1>
```